# Outputcache 1 action, 2 views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

So I have the following action which I am trying to add output caching to:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = OutputCacheProfileNames.Hours24)]
public ActionResult ContactUs()
{
  ContactUsModel model = _modelBuilder.BuildContactUsModel();

  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
  {
    return Json(StringFromPartial(partialTemplate, model), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
  else
  {
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

But this seem to cache the first view that is requested - ie either the json **OR** the normal view.

Is there a way to get the output caching to work for both views, without having to split them out of the same action?

Comment: try 
    [OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "name")]

Comment: check out varyby  
http://blog.danielcorreia.net/asp-net-mvc-vary-by-current-user/

Comment: @REDEVI_ unfortunately I can't use `VaryByParam` as no parameters are passed into the action,  I'll have a read of that custom thing, but looks like it may be the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You beat me to the punch in answering your own question, but I thought this code may still be helpful. Since varying by user is such a common scenario, you should probably account for being able to do that *and* your AJAX vary. This code will allow you vary on any number of custom parameters, by appending to a single string to vary on.

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(System.Web.HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    var args = custom.ToLower().Split(';');
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
        switch (arg)
        {
            case "user":
                sb.Append(User.Identity.Name);
                break;
            case "ajax":
                if (context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != null)
                {
                    // "XMLHttpRequest" will be appended if it's an AJAX request
                    sb.Append(context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]);
                }
                break;
            default:
                continue;
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then, you would just do something like the following if you need to vary by multiple custom params.

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = OutputCacheProfileNames.Hours24, VaryByCustom = "User;Ajax")]
```

Then, if you ever need additional custom vary params, you just keep adding case statements to cover those scenarios.

Comment: nice, didn't think about the multiple scenario case

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments by REDEVI_ for pointing me in the right direction, I have been able to solve this.

I changed my output caching to:

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = OutputCacheProfileNames.Hours24, VaryByCustom = "IsAjax")]
```

And then in my global.asax file, I added the following override:

```
    public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            switch (custom)
            {
                case "IsAjax":
                    return new HttpRequestWrapper(context.Request).IsAjaxRequest() ? "IsAjax" : "IsNotAjax";
            }
        }

        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
    }
```